# strange characters when sending information via DataOutputStream.writeUTF()

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to send information json format through socket but when the server sends and arrive at the beginning they have a certain special characters.

like ♠ * {Trace: {listfile ....}}
[image]

Class Client

```
public static void Connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException{
    String OUTPUT = getProperties();
    try{
    Tunnel = new Socket( HOSTNAME , PORT );
    InputStream = new DataInputStream(Tunnel.getInputStream());
    OutputStream = new DataOutputStream(Tunnel.getOutputStream());
    String OutSerial = "{ Trace: { "+OUTPUT+"}}";
    OutputStream.writeUTF(OutSerial);
    Tunnel.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Class Server

```
public static void Listening(String port) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        BufferedReader Input;
        int PORT = Integer.parseInt(port);
        sc =new ServerSocket(PORT);
        so =new Socket();
        so = sc.accept();
        Debug.DebugM("It is connected a bot.");
        Input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
        Output = new DataOutputStream(so.getOutputStream());
        String INPUT = null;
        while((INPUT = Input.readLine()) != null){

            System.out.println(INPUT);

        }}
```

How to solve?
Thanks

Comment: Also never silently swallow your exceptions

     }catch(Exception e){}

Comment: getProperties just to make a string in json.

Comment: I tested with trim() for clear null bytes but not work.

Comment: If you want to write it by DataOutputStream, you should read it by DataInputStream.  DataOutputStream.witeUTF() wirtes 2 byte length header.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the `writeUTF()` method is prepending some bytes. Use `readUTF()` instead of `readLine()` like you're doing.

See [DataInput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html) for the byte structure of the UTF representation.

Like so:

```
Input = new DataInputStream(so.getInputStream());
String INPUT = Input.readUTF();
System.out.println(INPUT);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Now Work !

Comment: Please make sure to mark this as the answer so others will know that this question has been answered. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `writeUTF()` for strings of arbitrary size. It's limited to a 16-bit length. And you can't use it at all unless the peer is going to use `readUTF()` to read it.

I would use `BufferedWriter.write()/newLine()` to write, and `BufferedReader.readLine()` to read.